# Which Google Sites URL is shown by google results: default or custom domain?

Tags: seo, domains, canonical-url, google-sites

About custom domain on Google sites, let's assume that we have this configuration :

- Default domain: `https://sites.google.com/view/example-com`
- Custom domain: `http://example.com`

After publication and setup of the custom domain, both work.

My question is: While both work when people search content on my website, which domain is shown by google (SEO) results, Default or Custom domain?

Comment: In general there are ways of making one or the other show up in search engines.  You can use meta tags or redirects to make ti happen.  However Google sites doesn't give you any control over those elements, so you are at the mercy of how they handle it.   I'm not sure how they do so.

Answer (score 2):

I could notice that *Google Sites* adds a `<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/…" />` tag to all pages of a *Google Sites* website when a custom domain is attached to it.
After the setting of the custom domain, *some* time is needed for it to become effectively canonical.